# dynamically accesing variables in python

Tags: python, dynamically-generated

Hello I am currently doing a project were I need up to 30.000 variables, which will be created dynamically. My problem however is accessing said variables dynamically , storing them in an array and accessing them like this works but I'd like to access them by name only. My code looks like:

```
NG=10
for i in range(1, NG+1 ):
    globals()[f"u_{i}"] = i
    print(u_{i})
```

Declaring variables like this works and they can be accessed by typing `u_1`, but the above print statement breaks the code.
Is there an option to access a variable similar to this in python?

Comment: Dynamically creating variable name can be done using globals() which is error prone. Use dictionary for sanity of your code

Comment: For your example change the print statement to print(f'u_{i}')

Answer (score 2):

You can access it the same way you set it:

```py
globals()[f"u_{i}"]
```

Except I highly recommend you **NOT** to use global variables. You can use a dictionary; eg.

```py
data = {}

data["some_key"] = 123
print(data["some_key"])
```

This will work the same way as does with global variables, except not having the pain of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dictionary would be the best option if you ask me. Just to give an example of a dummy assignment:

```
import random
a={} # the dictionary
random.seed(5)
for i in range(30000):
  a['u'+str(i+1)]=random.random() # Or whatever value you want to put in the variable  
print(a['u1']) # First variable and so on...
print(a['u2'])
```

Comment: ok that might be more sensible, but how do I access those dynamically, like print(a[ 'ui' ])?

Comment: Yes. You can either access them (if you just want to view) by print. If you want to use the variable somewhere, just reference as a['u1'] (or whatever term you need).